# Asterisk compilation issue

Tags: asterisk

I've downloaded source code of Asterisk from `http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/`
I'm getting error while compiling this from source code in Ubuntu 16.04.1. 
    Please suggest prerequisites for asterisk which needed for compilation.

I'm getting this error while trying to make -

```
./libasteriskssl.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
Makefile:321: recipe for target 'asterisk' failed  
make[1]: *** [asterisk] Error 1  
Makefile:368: recipe for target 'main' failed  
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

Please suggest......

Comment: Did you follow the hint on https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Checking+Asterisk+Requirements i.e. have  checked the requirements on the [System Requirements](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/System+Requirements) page or or installed all dependencies via the `install_prereq` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luiz Ricardo Ripardo is right about CRYPTO_num_locks being removed. I used the "--disable-asteriskssl" option to the configure script and was able to compile and install Asterisk version-15.1.2 on Raspbain-9-Stretch.

The use of this option is mentioned [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/New+in+11) under the "Build System" 
Section.

Answer (score 0):

Reading manuals as a service:

> https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Checking+Asterisk+Requirements:
>
> If you're installing Asterisk 1.6.1.0 or later, it comes with a shell script called `install_prereq.sh` in the `contrib/scripts` sub-directory.
> If you run `install_prereq test`, it will give you the exact commands to install the necessary system libraries on your operating system.
> If you run `install_prereq install`, it will attempt to download and install the prerequisites automatically.

Comment: I've to also compile & configure FreePBX for Asterisk. Would you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make an openssl downgrade. The function CRYPTO_num_locks has become obsolete in version 1.1.0. In my case (Debian Stretch) i edit /etc/apt/sources.list to Debian Jessie Repositories and run the apt-get update and upgrade commands.